# WCF Deserialization Error

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization

ERROR - Exception: System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException
Message: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter services.gmrlive.com/JupiterMobile/2009/01/01/:StatusDetails. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type X.X.X.Entities.StatusDetailCollection. Name cannot begin with the '5' character, hexadecimal value 0x35. Line 12, position 45.'.

I am tracing the wcf logs but i am unable to see the actual xml message. It fails to log the malformed message.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like your object name has a '5' character in beginning of the name, just as the error message suggested?

You can override the name by using the attribute:
[DataContract(Name="ZZZ")]

Comment: This service is working fine for other messages. I can see the message and works fine. Looks like something wrong with that particular message itself. StatusDetail object has a property called Name which is a string. Again, '5' in the begining should not bother a string field. StatusDetailCollection is collection object; public class StatusDetailCollection : KeyedCollection<string, StatusDetail>

Answer (score 0):

I dont think tracing does log your message. Anyways if you want to inspect the message you can use fiddler and inspect the request that is being sent over the wire to your WCF service. Also make sure that the message has proper namespaces for it to deserialize the message.